# Cannot invoke getUsers(String) on the primitive type int

Tags: java, irc

Im building a IRC Bot and came up with a Problem.

Im trying to get the user list, check the amount of tickets each user has and if they got tickets they should be added to the raffle-list(Vector).

Specially with this part i receive the Error:

```
raffleuserlist.add(ticketquery.getUsers("#"+ownerchannel)[i].getNick());
```

Error: "Cannot invoke getUsers(String) on the primitive type int"

Whole Code Snippet below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.getUsers("#"+ownerchannel).length; i++){
System.out.println("raffle-user> "+this.getUsers("#"+ownerchannel)[i].getNick());


// User got tickets? Y= Add him to the list N= nothing                  
ticketquery = MySQLAccess.gettickets(this.getUsers("#"+ownerchannel)[i].getNick());


    if(ticketquery >= 1){
            raffleuserlist.add(ticketquery.getUsers("#"+ownerchannel)[i].getNick());
    }
}
```

Did i do something wrong? Apreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling

```
ticketquery.getUsers
```

Where you most likely want

```
this.getUsers
```

`ticketquery` is an `int` and does not have any member methods that can be called.

Comment: Hmm Okay. the Amount of tickets wont get lost right? i want to set all (lets say user1 got 2 tickets) so there should be 2 entry in the list for the raffle. Or should i do it in a different way then?

Comment: The `ticketquery` object won't get "lost", meaning `go out of scope` until after the method finishes.

Comment: Thanks so far! :-) So i just need to find a different way of adding ppl to the list in an amount compared to their tickets. Or is a vector able to store both values to fit my raffle-system? Any Ideas from you?

Comment: The way I would do it personally is by using a `Map`. A map is a data structure that, funnily enough, MAPS one instance to another. So if you have a person object, you can map it to an Integer object which you can change according to number of tickets. Thus, a map is a `Collection` of Persons mapping to Integers, for example. This may be a bit more tricky than what you have here, though, especially if you're just starting out.

Comment: Hmm, sounds good. Yep, i just started 1-2 Months ago from scratch. i just wanted to "explore" java so i decided to start a irc bot project which is now pretty "huge" already. i got many games into it, connection to Mysql and able to storage/read data from it, voting system and other stuff and i made this out of nothing. i will definetly check that map-thing out :D Thanks alot! You are really a nice Person. Lucky to meet someone like you out there since many time when i ask stuff i just get almost no help / only downvotes or answers which wont help me. Thanks!

Comment: @user3220962 My pleasure. You remind me of me when I first started programming. The fact that you're interested in it and doing it on your own time for no-money 100% guarantees to me, a professional software developer, that you have a job in this field if you want it in the near future with just a little practice.

Comment: This would be great ^_^.

Comment: Hey Kon! i just finished my function and its working now. i will try the map-part in the future but would you like to check out the code i made and tell em if its okay or if there's anything to improve? also is there a way to contact you outside of this site? =) greetings!

Comment: @user3220962 I could take a look if it's not too long. I may give suggestions but wont' write anything for you. You can post your e-mail and I'll give you a way to reach me.

Comment: schneider606@msn.com  , Nah i dont want you to write anyhting for me. just give me suggestions =)